# Gaudiya vaishnava on maayavaada

Tags: vedanta, advaita, gaudiya-vaishnavism

From some Bengali Gaudiya vaishnavas i heard popular saying "sunle Mayavad Hobe sorbonash"

Is this mentioned in any authentic text of gaudiya school or books like Caitanya charitamrita?

Comment: What does "sunle Mayavad Hobe sorbonash" mean? Btw, what do you mean by Mayavada? Advaita?

Comment: you already know what it means .. samkhya and other scholars have also confirmed it. i dont know why such comment@TheDestroyer

Comment: @pandya. the answer and question both talks of caitanya charitamrit. why was that tag removed ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Mahaprabhu has preached so.

[Sri Chaitanya-Charitamrita ,Madhya khanda, 6.168](https://vedabase.io/en/library/cc/madhya/6/168/):

> **Translation:**
>   "The Buddhists do not recognize the authority of the Vedas; therefore they are considered agnostics. However, those who have taken shelter of the Vedic scriptures yet preach agnosticism in accordance with the Māyāvāda philosophy are certainly more dangerous than the Buddhists."
>
> **Purport :**
>   The Māyāvādīs' conception of spiritual existence is almost identical to the negation of material existence. The Māyāvādīs believe that there is nothing positive in spiritual life. As a result, they cannot understand devotional service or the worship of the Supreme Person, sac-cid-ānanda-vigraha (Bs. 5.1). The Māyāvādī philosophers consider Deity worship in devotional service to be pratibimba-vāda, or the worship of a form that is the reflection of a false material form. Thus the Lord's transcendental form, which is eternally blissful and full of knowledge, is unknown to Māyāvādī philosophers. Although the term "Bhagavān" is explicitly described in Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam, they cannot understand it. Brahmeti paramātmeti bhagavān iti śabdyate: "The Absolute Truth is called Brahman, Paramātmā and Bhagavān." (SB 1.2.11) The Māyāvādīs try to understand Brahman only, or, at the most, Paramātmā. However, they are unable to understand Bhagavān. Therefore the Supreme Personality of Godhead, Kṛṣṇa, says, māyayāpahṛta-jñānāḥ (BG 7.15). Because of the temperament of the Māyāvādī philosophers, real knowledge is taken from them. Because they cannot receive the mercy of the Lord, they will always be bewildered by His transcendental form. Impersonal philosophy destroys the three phases of knowledge—jñāna, jñeya and jñātā. As soon as one speaks of knowledge, there must be a person who is the knower, the knowledge itself and the object of knowledge. Māyāvāda philosophy combines these three categories; therefore the Māyāvādīs cannot understand how the spiritual potencies of the Supreme Personality of Godhead act. Because of their poor fund of knowledge, they cannot understand the distinction in the spiritual world between knowledge, the knower and the object of knowledge. Because of this, Śrī Caitanya Mahāprabhu considers the Māyāvādī philosophers more dangerous than the Buddhists.

**In the next verse, Mahaprabhu directly declares that anyone will be ruined if he or she listens to the Mayavadi Bhasya of the scriptures**.

But we must remember that such yugavataras preach some particular doctrine for particular Adhikaaries and so they make such comments. They do not have an iota of hatred against any saint or doctrine. Mahaprabhu took sannyasa from Sri Keashava Bharati and followed the rules of Dasanami sannyasa. He sacrificed sikha-sutra as mentioned in Sri Chaitanya Charitamrita.But modern Gaudiya Vaishnavas represent him with sikha and kanthimala!

Sri Chaitanya ordered His devotees: "Anya deva, Anya sastra ninda naa koribe" "jibe samman dibe jaani Krishna-adhisthan". (Do not criticise any deity or scripture,.Respect everybody asnKrishna resides in all.

( Ref: Sri Chaitanyadev, Swami Saradeshananda, Udbodhan).
The translations of Bhaktivedanta Swami has been used.

Comment: Actually you should have quoted the 169th verse, not 168th verse. In 168th, Mahaprabhu says "veda nā māniyā bauddha haya ta’ nāstika
vedāśraya nāstikya-vāda bauddhake adhika". In 169th, He's saying jīvera nistāra lāgi’ sūtra kaila vyāsa **māyāvādi-bhāṣya śunile haya sarva-nāśa**.

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury: Thanks.I have added it.Regards

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it was said by Chaitanya Mahaprabhu to Sarvabhouma Bhattacharya, in *[Chaitanya Charitamrita](https://vedabase.io/en/library/cc/madhya/6/169/)*, *Madhya Lila*, Chapter 6, Verse 169:

> *jīvera nistāra lāgi’ sūtra kaila vyāsa
>   **māyāvādi-bhāṣya śunile haya sarva-nāśa***
>
> “Śrīla Vyāsadeva presented the Vedānta philosophy for the deliverance of conditioned souls, **but if one hears the Mayavadi commentary, everything is spoiled**.

Comment: thnx so much.i hv included that verse also.Regards

Comment: What language is this? Bengali?

Comment: @TheDestroyer It's Bengali.

Comment: Where's mention of Adi Shankara in the verse you quote? It only mentions mayavad.

Comment: @Lokesh That's how Srila Prabhupada has translated. Adi Shankara has been indirectly mentioned as "Acharya" in the particular chapter and it is very clear anyway who Mahaprabhu is referring to in that chapter if you read it (https://vedabase.io/en/library/cc/madhya/6/)

Comment: I don't think so. Mayavad of Chaitanya Mahaprabhu is not same as Advaita. Although Srila Prabhupada interpreted mayavad as Advaita. That's my understanding. Could you mention exactly where in the chapter Mahaprabhu refers to Adi Shankaracharya?

Comment: Anyhow, whatever be the case the translation which you mentioned above is far from accurate. If you correct it, I can take my downvote back

Comment: @Lokesh Read from the 180th verse: (https://vedabase.io/en/library/cc/madhya/6/). Mahaprabhu even quotes Padma Purana to say Adi Shankara (Shiva) was ordered to preach false philosophy.

Comment: @Lokesh Nah, I don't care about reputation and anyway I don't have any other English translation of Chaitanya Charitamrita. And it is definitely refering to Adi Shankara. I have studied the chapter in great detail. Translations are usually like this.

Comment: You just need to remove Adi Shankaracharya commentary with mayavad commentary. The rest translation is fine

Comment: @Lokesh Uff fine 

Comment: Mahaprabhu was from lineage of Advaita parampara only. He was eka Dandi Sanyasi. It doesn't make sense that He is ridiculing Adi Shankaracharya.

Comment: @Lokesh what is Mayavada according to Chaitanya, if not Advaita?

Comment: Mayavad means everything is Maya while Advaita is everything is Brahman. In mayavad there is positive existence of Maya which overpowers Atman. In Advaita Atman is always supreme and Maya doesn't exist.